# Execute Immediate to UPDATE via for loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do a number of data updates as follows:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MDM_RUN_DATA_MAPPING
     IS
        sqlString VARCHAR2(2000) := '';
        CURSOR csr_updates 
        IS
            SELECT  trim(table_name) AS table_name, 
                    trim(column_name) AS column_name, 
                    trim(old_value) AS old_value, 
                    trim(new_value) AS new_value 
            FROM C_MDM_MAPPING_TABLE 
            WHERE area = 'MDM' and rownum < 10
            AND run_update = 'Y' ;

    BEGIN
          FOR rec IN csr_updates 
          LOOP
             BEGIN
                sqlString := 'UPDATE ' || rec.table_name || 
                      ' SET ' || rec.column_name || ' = ''' || rec.new_value || '''
                      WHERE TRIM(' || rec.column_name || ') = ''' || rec.old_value || ''';'  ; 

                INSERT INTO C_MDM_ERROR_LOG  ( msg ) VALUES ( sqlString ); 

                dbms_output.put_line(sqlString) ; -- works, giving correct SQL
                execute immediate sqlString ;  -- fails

             END;
          END LOOP;
          COMMIT;

    END PROC_MDM_RUN_DATA_MAPPING;
    /
```

The procedure compiles and generates the correct SQL for each of the data updates - example below:

```
    UPDATE S_CFM_UNIVERSITY_ALL SET MASTER_UNI_NAME = 'Chung-Ang University'
                      WHERE TRIM(MASTER_UNI_NAME) = 'Chung Ang University';
```

but the execute immediate statement gives the error
      "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

;  
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue."

I have tried excluding the trailing semi colon, but that returns the error

```
  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You don't need semi colon in sqlstring when using with execute immediate, are you sure that your cursor query is returning values for all columns? There may be a row with null values and causing sql command not properly ended error

Comment: Yes, rs is right about this. Remove the `;` inside the dynamic SQL string and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks rs - all columns are returning values but some values contain a single quote, which I'll need to check for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generating the SQL without the embedded newline, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MDM_RUN_DATA_MAPPING IS
  sqlString VARCHAR2(2000) := '';

  CURSOR csr_updates IS
    SELECT  trim(table_name) AS table_name, 
            trim(column_name) AS column_name, 
            trim(old_value) AS old_value, 
            trim(new_value) AS new_value 
      FROM C_MDM_MAPPING_TABLE 
      WHERE area = 'MDM' AND
            rownum < 10 AND
            run_update = 'Y';
  BEGIN
    FOR rec IN csr_updates LOOP
      sqlString := 'UPDATE ' || rec.table_name || 
                   ' SET ' || rec.column_name || ' = ''' || rec.new_value ||
                   ''' WHERE TRIM(' || rec.column_name || ') = ''' ||
                   rec.old_value || '''';

      INSERT INTO C_MDM_ERROR_LOG  ( msg ) VALUES ( sqlString ); 

      dbms_output.put_line(sqlString) ; -- works, giving correct SQL
      execute immediate sqlString ;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
  END PROC_MDM_RUN_DATA_MAPPING;
```

I removed the semicolon in the generated SQL as I believe it's not needed, and got rid of the BEGIN...END pair inside the loop which is also not needed.

I hope this helps.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help - the answer above are correct in that the trailing semi colon is not needed, but as a follow up - there was a 2nd issue which was single quotes in the data.

Changing the cursor as follows fixed that issue

```
    SELECT  trim(table_name) AS table_name, 
            trim(column_name) AS column_name, 
            REPLACE(trim(old_value),'''','''''') AS old_value, 
            REPLACE(trim(new_value),'''','''''') AS new_value 
    FROM C_MDM_MAPPING_TABLE
```

Table and column names are known to be ok (they come from the system), but it gets back to "Never trust the input".

Thanks